# foreach inside foreach error

Tags: php, arrays, oop, mysqli

here my code in class.php:

```
 public function select(){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT country FROM `country`") or die($this->conn->error);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            return $result;
        }
    }


public function read(){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT segment FROM `segments`") or die($this->conn->error);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

and now in index.php i did this:

```
                            <th class="text-center">country</th>

                            <th class="text-center">segments</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php

                require 'class.php';

                $conn = new db_class();
                $read = $conn->select();
                                    $test = $conn->read();

                while($fetch = $read->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)&& $fetch1 = $test->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
                                        foreach ($fetch1 as $field => $values) {


                                      foreach($fetch as $field=>$value){
   echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td>'
           . '<td>'. $values .'</td>';
}

                                        }
}       


            ?>




            </tbody>
        </table>
```

im just trying to fetch data from 2 tables and put them in one html table

i get this error for 6 times:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\segments\countrySegment.php on line 59`

im just trying to fetch data from 2 tables and put them in one html table 
and if any one know how, i want for every country a drop down menu with segment values inside
any idea? thank u in advance

Comment: can you print `$fetch` && `$fetch1` in the loop?

Comment: it came with this error :Array to string conversion @AgamBanga

Comment: do `print_r($fetch)` && `print_r($fetch1)` instead of `echo`

Comment: You'd have to `print_r()` in order for it to print

Comment: Are the 2 tables you're selecting from related? Like do they have a common column?

Comment: same error as before but this what it shows:                                     Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\segments\countrySegment.php on line 61
Array ( [segment] => food ) 1 @AgamBanga

Comment: yes i have created another table and  i joined then using this query:                                                                                                                                                                                select * from countrysegments 
       inner join country on countrysegments.country_id  = country.id
       inner join segments on countrysegments.segment_id = segments.id @RBCunhaDesign

Comment: it means you are getting array in `$fetch` but only `1` in `$fetch1` as per output from print. Check the query

Comment: You have too many questions with none accepted and all within 24 hours. If you wish to remain in good standings, you should mark the ones that provided you with solutions as solved. *Be a good neighbour* ;-)

Comment: Seeing your question history; it appears that you are basically asking the same question over and over again, but using code borrowed from other answers. That isn't how things work on Stack and you could get flagged for moderation. @eddyabikhalil

Answer (score 1):

This because of array pointer issue

```
foreach ($fetch1 as $field => $values) {
   foreach($fetch as $field=>$value){
      echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td>'
           . '<td>'. $values .'</td>';
   }
}
```

first time second foreach prints everything next time it has no value it points beyond the value..

so you need to reset the array using reset

```
foreach ($fetch1 as $field => $values) {
   reset($fetch)
   foreach($fetch as $field=>$value){
      echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td>'
           . '<td>'. $values .'</td>';
   }
}
```

or you can save it a temporary variable

```
foreach ($fetch1 as $field => $values) {
   $fetchtmp = $fetch;
   foreach($fetchtmp as $field=>$value){
      echo '<tr><td>' . $value . '</td>'
           . '<td>'. $values .'</td>';
   }
}
```

Comment: thank u but its not working still have the same error

Comment: which option u tried

Comment: both option @v-sugumar